# Entity framework using statement with Dapper

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, dapper

All of my existing using statements look like the following:

```
using (var context = new AppContext())
{
}
```

Now what if I want to use Dapper to pass a sql string directly to the database rather than:

```
context.Database.SqlQuery(sql);
```

After looking at the Dapper documenation it looks like it just uses a regular connection string. I am unsure of how to adjust my using statement declaration.

I want to be able to do the following like all of the Dapper examples show:

```
connection.Query(sql);
```

I am really hoping dapper will help me with populating custom properties. For example I used a partial class to extend one of my entity framework properties. Currently when I use pass a sql query through linq this property does not get populated even though it is in the Select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `context.Database.Connection.Query<T>()` from Dapper since it is just an extension to `DbConnection`.

Comment: Database.Connection.Query is unavailable to me. I installed the Dapper dot net Nuget package to my Data Library. Is there anything else I needed to do? Do I have to make one of my classes inherit from IDbConnection or something?

Comment: Can you access `context.Connection`? This will return the `DbConnection` object needed for Dapper

Comment: I can access context.Database.Connection. Kamo was telling me to just do context.Database.Connection.Query so I could still use my Entity Framework using statement, but intellisense is telling me that Query is not a valid extension method.

Comment: Have you included the correct `using` statement in your class?

Comment: My mistake... I didn't add using Dapper to my file. Sorry guys and thanks for the help!